# ОшибкаFATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, json

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView uid;
TextView name1;
TextView email1;
Button Btngetdata;

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://proforientator.info/?json=get_page&page_id=574";

//JSON Node Names
private static final String TAG_PAGE = "page";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
private static final String TAG_CONTENT = "content";

JSONArray page = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById( R.id.getdata);
    Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new JSONParse().execute(url);

        }
    });


}
public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Integer , JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String[] args;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
        name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);


    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array
            page = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PAGE);
            JSONObject c = page.getJSONObject(0);

            // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_CONTENT);


            //Set JSON Data in TextView
            uid.setText(id);
            name1.setText(name);
            email1.setText(email);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

}`

JsonParser Activity

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        HttpEntity httpEntity;
        try (DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( url );

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpPost );
        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}
Лог ошибки

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.execute
                                                                       at com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:43)
                                                                       at com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.MainActivity$JSONParse.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                       at com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.MainActivity$JSONParse.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.close
                                                                       at com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:44)

введите сюда код
Activity com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2cd83020 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
                                                                  android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2cd83020 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
                                                                      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
                                                                      at com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.MainActivity$JSONParse.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
                                                                      at com.cz.volleyjsonobj.volleyjsonobj.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

12-25 20:51:22.075 303-426/system_process E/ThrottleService: problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Народ,помогите! не могу понять что делать...(((Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ сам. в gradle  добавил useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' обновил и пошло)))При использовании  Apache HTTP для SDK уровня 23 необходимо подтягивать так))

Comment: Правильный ответ - не использовать устаревший  Apache HTTP client. А заменить его чем то более современным. Тем более что имена Ваших пакетов намекают что у Вас уже подключена библиотека Volley